# how to toastUi Viewer using in reactjs typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, toast-ui-editor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bA96x.png)
I want useing Viewer
vscode told me can't element viewer and height
my toastui version : "@toast-ui/react-editor": "^3.1.1"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWlU1.png)

and initialValue not show message in object
what to do I do?

Comment: Hey there, you should use `markdown` for adding code snippets in your questions. 
please google `Markdown Cheatsheet`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: thank you for my question! I had solve it just editor and viewer component write same file!